# Problema con @Header en Retrofit2

Tags: android, laravel-5, retrofit

Necesito consumir desde Android una api desarrollada en Laravel, agregué dos headers al método del login, pero no encuentro la manera de que reconozca Content-Type.

```
@POST("auth/login")
Call<UserLoginResponse> login(@Body UserLogin loginBody,
                              @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                              @Header("X-Requested-With") String xRequested);
```

también probé de esta manera

```
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type:application/json",
            "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest"
    })
    @POST("auth/login")
    Call<UserLoginResponse> login(@Body UserLogin loginBody);
```

pero el resultado es el mismo:
"The given data was invalid."

**ACTUALIZACION**

Desde Postman recupero los datos sin problemas
[image: Postman con las dos cabeceras]

Cuando quito la cabecera content-type me da el mismo error que desde Retrofit, por lo que me hace pensar que no la reconoce.
[image: Postman con una cabecera]

Comment: has pruebas con insomnia o postman es mas facil ver el error

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez ahí agregué las pruebas con Postman.

Comment: Porque no pruebas de este modo: @Headers("content-type: application/json; X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest")

Comment: @KenjiKawaidaVillegas tampoco...

Comment: si me pasas la url podria probar el consumo @josetuzin

Comment: @KenjiKawaidaVillegas grancias, el endpoint (sin los espacios, obviamente) es  https: //www.jm ovil .com/api/auth/login

Comment: el body mas por favor para ver que es lo que envias

Comment: @KenjiKawaidaVillegas {
 "email":"jose@fjose.com",
 "password":"jose00"
}

Comment: Encontré una solución alternativa [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817362/sending-json-in-post-request-with-retrofit2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He realizado pruebas con los datos que me entregaste y me funciono de esta manera:

Mi clase **ApiClient**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory;

/**
 * Created by Kenji Kawaida on 23-Nov-16.
 */
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String url) {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
                .newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        if(url.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

La clase **ApiInterface**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers("content-type: application/json")
    @POST("login")
    Call<UserLoginResponse> login(@Body String jsonObject);
}
```

La clase de **Servicios** donde hago el llamado

```
public class Services {
    private Context context;
    private ApiInterface apiServices;
    private Gson gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();

    public Services(Context context, String url){
        apiServices = ApiClient.getClient(url).create(ApiInterface.class);
        this.context = context;
    }

public UserLoginResponse login(Object object) throws IOException {
        Call<UserLoginResponse> call = apiServices.login(gsonBuilder.toJson(object));
        String url = call.request().url().toString();

        UserLoginResponse respuestaWS = respuestaWS = call.execute().body();

        return respuestaWS;
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo el Asynctask donde llamo el metodo:

```
private class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Services services = new Services(SplashActivity.this, "https://www.jmovil.com/api/auth/");

            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.email = "jose@fjose.com";
            usuario.password = "jose00";

            UserLoginResponse userLoginResponse;

            try {
                userLoginResponse = services.login(usuario);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public class Usuario{
            String email;
            String password;
        }
    }
```

Funciona perfectamente el llamado y realiza el parseo con los datos solicitados